# Linked Fields - Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I can not make the Linked Fields option work.
When the event is triggered, the error below appears in the console.

Funny that even the basic datepicker functionality works when events are active.

JavaScript Code

```
jQuery(container).find(".xcrud-datepicker").each(function() {
var element = jQuery(this);
$(function() {
element.datetimepicker();
var range_start = element.data("rangestart");
var range_end = element.data("rangeend");
if (range_start) {
    element.datetimepicker({
    useCurrent : false
    // Important! See issue #1075
    });
}
if (range_end) {
    element.on("dp.changes", function(e) {
    var target = element.parent().find('input[name="' + range_end + '"]');
    jQuery(target).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
}
if (range_start) {
    element.on("dp.changes", function(e) {
    var target = element.parent().find('input[name="' + range_start + '"]');
    jQuery(target).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
}
});
});
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
<input class="xcrud-input xcrud-datepicker form-control" data-required="1" type="text" data-type="datetime" value="" name="Y2xpZW50ZXMuY2xpX2NyaWFjYW8-" data-rangeend="WTJ4cFpXNTBaWE11WTJ4cFgyTnlhV0ZqWVc5ZmRHOC0-">
<span> até </span>
<input class="xcrud-input xcrud-datepicker form-control" type="text" data-type="datetime" value="" name="Y2xpZW50ZXMuY2xpX2NyaWFjYW9fdG8-" data-rangestart="WTJ4cFpXNTBaWE11WTJ4cFgyTnlhV0ZqWVc4LQ--">
```

Error on JS console, when event is triggered

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minDate' of undefined
```

Comment: did you include `moment.js`?

Comment: Yes!
The error is in line jQuery(target).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
It can not read data("DateTimePicker") on the element.

Comment: Are you sure that `jQuery(target)` has matched what you expected? I think that `jQuery(target)` is not a _DateTimePicker_, anyway I fear that the HTML you provided is not enough to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. When you print to the console `console.log()`, the printed object is correct.